# One to many relation in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two tables `News` and `Comments`. The `Comments` table has two foreign key columns `UserId` and `NewsId`.

When I get a `News` item by id in Entity Framework Core, comments are null.

News model class:

```
public partial class News
{
    public News()
    {
        NewsComments = new HashSet<NewsComments>();
        NewsLikes = new HashSet<NewsLikes>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int PublisherId { get; set; }
    public int? ViewCount { get; set; }
    public int? LikeCount { get; set; }
    public int? CommentCount { get; set; }

    public virtual NewsCategories Category { get; set; }
    public virtual NewsPublishers Publisher { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsComments> NewsComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsLikes> NewsLikes { get; set; }
}
```

Comments model class:

```
public partial class NewsComments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAccept { get; set; }

    public virtual News News { get; set; }
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

Get news method:

```
public News GetNews(int id)
{
    return _db.News.Find(id);
}
```

Comment: _db.News.Include(w => w.NewsComment).Find(id) . if my syntax is wrong please fix for yourself. in summary, You will need to use Include() :)

Comment: @Md.TazbirUrRahmanBhuiyan 
'IIncludableQueryable<News, ICollection<NewsComments>>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no accessible extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'IIncludableQueryable<News, ICollection<NewsComments>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You will have to use Where() instead of Find as Inlcude() returns IQuerable() object

Comment: @Md.TazbirUrRahmanBhuiyan output : Expected ',' instead of ''

Comment: can you give me a screenshot? i don't understand the output

Comment: @Md.TazbirUrRahmanBhuiyan https://pasteboard.co/IpLH03y.jpg

Comment: can you paste the updated code block here

Comment: @Md.TazbirUrRahmanBhuiyan IQueryable<News> news = _db.News.Include(w => w.NewsComments).Where(n => n.Id == id);

Comment: Are you trying to return News object as the response? If you are trying to do that, you will need to return a single object rather then the an IQuerable object. Try to use FirstOrDefault() or FirstOrDefaultAsync() after the Where(n => n.Id == id) . Please share method screen shot if you are still having trouble

Comment: @Md.TazbirUrRahmanBhuiyan https://pasteboard.co/IpLMslV.jpg

Comment: What's the error now after updating the code

Comment: @Md.TazbirUrRahmanBhuiyan output is Expected ',' instead of '' , but when i debug, news and comments received from database, my controller return type is object.

Comment: I think you are expecting json format data. Try googling about how to return complex object in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF if you are set by default with eager loading so you need to include the model property of the relationship like so :

```
public News GetNews(int id)
{
    return _db.News.Include(n=>n.NewsComments).Find(id);
}
```

Unless you have have forced to lazy load but still you have to setup the relationship on the context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NewsComments>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(nc => nc.News)
    .WithMany(n => n.NewsComments)
    .HasForeignKey(nc => nd.NewsId);
 });
```